# Flutter: Is there a way to create a new flutter project and pull in the main files from a backup?

Tags: android, flutter, firebase

I just downloaded the latest updated for Android Studio - Electric Eel. The problem is that now I'm getting a bunch of strange errors that weren't there just before the update. So I was wondering - is there a way to "restart" my project in the new version of Android Studio? I'm thinking I would need to just create a new flutter project and then manually paste in all the Dart files, the `pubspec.yaml`, and the `AndroidManifest.xml` (all the files I've changed). And then for the `build.gradle` files I'll just copy paste the exact lines that I had to add for my project. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: I think it would be better if you properly go through your error first, maybe there will be only one error causing the others. Worth giving a try.

Answer (score 0):

**You can run `flutter clean`.**

Or you can delete the /build folder under your /app-project folder manually if you cannot run flutter command.

then **hot Reload the project again**.

I think it will help.

**if it don't work then please share the error images.**